# Single domain OS crash, how to restore to new hardware/install

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I had a single controller domain (Win2008) and the PDC died after a windows update.

I have tried various repair operations with no luck. I do have the system drive intact.

How do I import or restore this data to a new install of Win2008 and recover my domain?

Comment: You're out of luck I'm afraid. Unless you have a backup of the System State of the failed server you can't restore AD.

Comment: Apparently my stuff wont boot due to an installed system update.. 
I'm looking into trying the stuff at http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/109213-windows-update-uninstall-console-level.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the domain restore mode and it worked.

Had to do with base device drivers. Windows driver search resolved the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Restore from backups.  You should always MAKE SURE you have backups before you apply updates.

If you don't have backups and you cannot get the system to boot, then you have one more chance (not free) that I'm aware of: [UTools Umove](http://utools.com/UMove.asp).  I've never used it, but it's the ONLY tool I've ever heard of that even has a chance at recovering your Active Directory.  Consider how much time it may take you to manually migrate user profiles and rejoin each computer to the domain compared to the $130 and using this tool to recover the system.  It's not free, but it may save you money and time.

Answer (score 0):

Now add another domain controller...

Comment: lol yeah. I did.